# I am passing a set of N values to a loop but cant get it to print an ouput

Tags: python, loops, numpy, error-handling

I cannot seem to get an output when I pass numbers to the function. I need to get the computed value and subtract it from the exact.  Is there something I am not getting right?

```
def f1(x):
  f1 = np.exp(x)
  return f1;
def trapezoid(f,a,b,n):
   '''Computes the integral of functions using the trapezoid rule
   f = function of x
   a = upper limit of the function
   b = lower limit of the function
   N = number of divisions'''
   h   = (b-a)/N
   xi  = np.linspace(a,b,N+1)
   fi  = f(xi)
   s   = 0.0
   for i in range(1,N):
       s = s + fi[i]
   s = np.array((h/2)*(fi[0] + fi[N]) + h*s)
   print(s)
   return s
exactValue = np.full((20),math.exp(1)-1)
a  = 0.0;b = 1.0  # integration interval [a,b]
computed = np.empty(20)
E=np.zeros(20)
exact=np.zeros(20)
N=20
def convergence_tests(f, a, b, N):
 n = np.zeros(N, 1);
 E = np.zeros(N, 1);
 Exact = math.exp(1)-1
 for i in range(N):
   n[i] = 2^i
   computed[i] = trapezoid(f, a, b, n[i])
   E = abs(Exact - computed)
 print(E, computed)
 return E, computed
```

Comment: Can you be specific about which function you are passing parameters to that is not working correctly?

Comment: You have defined a function named `f1()` but you never call it...

Comment: The trapezoid function defined in the first part of the code

Comment: I called it @ f1. same problem

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.

Comment: `trapezoid` is only called from `convergence_test`, but you never call `convergence_test`.

Comment: There's more than a single thing wrong here - please make an effort and read up on the basics of defining a function and calling it. Also, I'd recommend installing a good Python editor (I like PyCharm myself, and it's free), because it will point out some of the errors with your code automatically and help you learn faster.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined several functions, but your main program never calls any of them.  In fact, your "parent" function `convergence_test` *cannot* be called, because it's defined at the bottom of the program.

I suggest that you use incremental programming: write a few lines; test those before you proceed to the next mini-task in your code.  In the posting, you've written about 30 lines of active code, without realizing that virtually *none* of it actually executes.  There may well be several other errors in this; you'll likely have a difficult time fixing all of them to get the expected output.

Start small and grow incrementally.

Comment: Thanks. I need that. I am kinda new to coding.Did this and still no result `import numpy as np
import math
import Trapezoid as trapezoidal
def f1(x):
   f1 = np.exp(x)
   return f1
a = 0
b = 1
M=20
def convergence_tests(f,a,b,N):
    #Err =np.zeros(N,1)
    T =np.zeros(N)
    #Exact = np.full((20),math.exp(1)-1)
    for i in range (M):
        N=2*i
        for j in range (N):
            T[j]=trapezoidal(f1,a,b,N)
Z = convergence_tests(f1,a,b,N)
print(Z)`

Comment: If you expect help with code, we need you to post it as code, not as a single-line comment.  Also, what you've posted bypasses my suggestion of incremental programming.